# Drupal + jcarousel + right scroll images are not loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal-7, jcarousel

Hii friends I got a problem with jcarousel module, everything is working perfect but except when I first launch the site the initial 6 images shows up ok. But, if i click on the forward/backward to scroll images i get a total "blank" page. One has to click 2/3 times to get remaining images.. Please help me how do i overcome from this issue....

1) If i press **ctrl+f5** this issue occurs again... if i press **enter** on the url it works perfect....

2) If i **scroll left** when i refresh it works good but if i **scroll right** at starting it takes minimum 3 clicks to load images...

Comment: I got solved this its a Css Problem